# MapThread for any combination of variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a set of regular (mod 5) matrices N2 and I would like to get the group generated by these matrices in Mathematica:
My approach was to use a function f doing the matrix multiplication and g for mod 5 and then I wanted to use MapThread

```
M= Function[{x,y},x.y];
g = Function[z, Mod[z, 5]]
g /@ MapThread[M, {N2,N2}]
```

The problem is that MapThread is inserting only pairs of elements that are at the same position in the lists. I would like to insert any pair of elements in N. To get the group generated by the matrices in N I would just repeat this and update N2 every time.

E.g. let N2 ={A,B}

```
g /@ MapThread[M, {N2,N2}]
```

would return {B^2,A^2}, while I want it to return any product of matrices in N2, i.e. {A^2,AB,BA,B^2}.

Comment: Hi Michalis, welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm not sure whether I can answer your question, but I'd like to remark on a few things that I see in your code. First, you use the reserved 'word' N as a variable. Second, is `f[{x,y},x.y]`  supposed to be some kind of function definition? I don't quite understand it.

Comment: hey, thanks for the remarks! In my code I called it N2, thats why I didnt notice this mistake and I corrected the line with f too :) Sorry, I just started Mathematica yesterday.

Comment: Additionally, what is the definition of the function M, and where do you use f?

Comment: I hope you'll enjoy Mathematica as much as I (and all the others here) do. There's much to learn but I assure you it'll be worthwhile.

Comment: thanks again :) f should be M... sorry I am a bit tired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need `Outer`:

```
In[27]:= n = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {3, 2, 2}];

In[28]:= Outer[mFunc, n, n, 1]

Out[28]= {{mFunc[{{3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 5}, {2, 4}}], 
  mFunc[{{3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}], 
  mFunc[{{3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{4, 4}, {5, 1}}]}, {mFunc[{{3, 4}, {4, 
     3}}, {{3, 5}, {2, 4}}], 
  mFunc[{{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}], 
  mFunc[{{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {5, 1}}]}, {mFunc[{{4, 4}, {5, 
     1}}, {{3, 5}, {2, 4}}], 
  mFunc[{{4, 4}, {5, 1}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}], 
  mFunc[{{4, 4}, {5, 1}}, {{4, 4}, {5, 1}}]}}

In[29]:= n

Out[29]= {{{3, 5}, {2, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 3}}, {{4, 4}, {5, 1}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question, but if your intention is to get all combinations of the two matrices A,B you could use Tuples combined with Apply (which you may use in its functional form with square brackets or as many here do in initially cryptic prefix operator form @@@ = Apply at level 1):

In[24]:= Dot @@@ Tuples[{A, B}, 2]

Out[24]= {A.A, A.B, B.A, B.B}

Comment: Thanks! Thats elegant! Unfortunately I can't upvote you and I accepted the first answer!

Comment: @Michalis No problemo. It won't be  long before you can vote. Just ask a few more questions and you're done. BTW I have never tried this, but I've heard you can switch your selected answer.